# IF/ELSE condition: frequency of continuously

Tags: c#, wpf

I created a C# / WPF application and I want to change WPF form's color at runtime as per condition  task is if user select red color form change to red and if user select green color form color make green

user select color in combobox (red, green) and I write code in combobox click event code like

```
if ( color.Text== "green")
{
   SolidColorBrush bg = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.green);
   g.Background = bg;   //g is stack panel name 
}
else
{
   SolidColorBrush bg = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.red);
   g.Background = bg;
}
```

but at runtime I selected green color form color change in to red instead of green.

Comment: You shouldn't put this code in the click event but in the SelectedIndexChanged event.

Answer (score 1):

That's because `color.Text` doesn't equal `"green"`?

Try using `(string)color.SelectedValue`.

Oh - and @Fuex points out (although assumed that you are on Windows Forms, when in fact you are on WPF) - you do not use the `Click` event - because no selection will have been made.

You need to use the [`SelectionChanged`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.selector.selectionchanged.aspx) event.

After moving your logic to that handler, you should also be able to move back to using `.Text`

Comment: actully i write ur code e.g if((color.Text)color.SelectedValue)  i find SelectedValue not found

Comment: Use the [`SelectionChanged` event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.selector.selectionchanged.aspx) - `Click` is not the correct event to do this in